# Silverlight tri-state checkbox databinding to object property calculating value

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, binding, checkbox

So I have this little problem making this to work:

1. I have silverlight client app that has custom usercontrol with tri-state checkbox with two-way binding
2. After user changes checkbox value, function underlying the property translates the value to integer:

   ```
      -1 nothing
       0 false
       1 true
   ```
3. After user saves data from dialog box, all data(complex object) is being serializes and sent over to webservice and stored in SQL db.
4. When client requests saved data back from webservice, it get back that object OK
5. When I try to bind that returned deserialized object(EA) back to checkbox like this:

   ```
          With cC
              Dim b As New Binding("AllowedTo.Create")
              b.Source = EA
              b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
              .SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, b)
          End With
   ```

it only works ok if the values are true or false, but if value is nothing, as the checkbox is tri-state, it should turn to that third state - undefined - with minus sign [-], but it dosent.
It just stays at false state - empty with no check, like it would be false.

What could be the problem?

*Sorry for my english, its not my mother language*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an integer for this, use a Nullable Bool (Bool?). Two way binding works well, it converts:

- Checked == true
- Unchecked == false
- Indeterminate == null

Serialization isn't a problem with nullable bools, in fact you don't even have to check if the SQL field value is NULL, since it will be a valid state, and using a bool field in the SQL database will even reduce it's size a bit ;)

If your database is set, and you can't change it, write a converter to convert your integer to a nullable bool for the binding, shouldn't take more then 2 minutes.

Comment: I didnt mention, that i already have property "AllowedTo.Create", witch is of type nullable(of boolean). It converts this value back and forth from this integer property. But when it returns NOTHING, checkbox should show indeterminate, but it just stays at unchecked state. If my property returns true or false, then it works OK

Comment: 1) a property is not a converter... Use a converter for converting the value at a binding.

Comment: 2) it can't return "NOTHING" as you said, it can return a value or throw an expcetion, the value can be null, but it's not NOTHING

Comment: 3) I'm pretty sure tri-state checkboxed bound to nullable bools 2 way are working in Silverlight, because I was developing solutions where it was needed. Maybe you're using a rather old version of SL? If I remember correctly when I was developing this project in SL4.

Comment: 4) if it still doesn't work, there must be another error in your code, I can't help it this way, post your XAML of the Checkbox, the converter and the property which is it bound to, then I will look at it and help you figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Thank You! I found out another function working with data after recieving back from server and apending multiple data structures(trees) togeather calculated the value wrong. Binding realy works OK

Answer (score 0):

Since such a technique is really native to the checkbox, I would recommend creating a custom control to handle the 3 different states for that boolean value.